# R function to fix automatically formatted data

Tags: r, date

I am currently analyzing a baseball data set that has the count data included, however, some of the data has automatically been formatted as a date.

I have already tried using as.numeric but it does not help. I have provided a sample of the data below:

```
 Count(Factor) 0-0 0-1 0-2 1-Feb 1-Jan 1-Mar 2-Feb 2-Jan 2-Mar
               Feb-00 Jan-00 Mar-00
```

I would like to remove the date format. For instance, I want to see 1-Feb as 1-2, 1-Jan as 1-1, 1-Mar as 1-3, Feb-00 as 2-0.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to do so?

Comment: The `lubridate` package might help, but you have some very different formats there. I'm assuming that `2-Feb` is the 2nd day of February, do you interpret it as something else? Similar,y is `Feb-00` the month of February in 2000? Lots of inference and assumption here, I'm not certain I want to attempt something without a lot more context.

Comment: Where is the conversion to dates happening?  Is it already in the dataset that you're bringing into R, or is it something that R is doing as you load the dataset?

Comment: @A.S.K. it is like that in the excel sheet as well. It would probably be easier just to fix in Excel

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the abbreviated months with their relevant calendar position by referencing `months.abb`. Below I have created a general function using Base R.

```r
## function to apply 
month_num <- function(x){
  if (! grepl('\\w{3}', x))
    return(x)
  gsub('/?\\w{3}', as.character(match(regmatches(x, regexpr('(\\w{3})', x)), month.abb)), x)
}

## vector
strings <- c( '0-0', '0-1' ,'0-2', '1-Feb', '1-Jan', '1-Mar', '2-Feb', '2-Jan', '2-Mar', 'Feb-00', '/Jan-00', 'Mar-00')
sapply(strings, month_num, USE.NAMES = FALSE)
#>  [1] "0-0"  "0-1"  "0-2"  "1-2"  "1-1"  "1-3"  "2-2"  "2-1"  "2-3"  "2-00"
#> [11] "1-00" "3-00"

## data.frame or matrix
tmp <- data.frame(
  strings = c( '0-0', '0-1' ,'0-2', '1-Feb', '1-Jan', '1-Mar', '2-Feb', '2-Jan', '2-Mar', 'Feb-00', '/Jan-00', 'Mar-00')
)
tmp$strings <- apply(tmp, 1, month_num)
tmp
#>    strings
#> 1      0-0
#> 2      0-1
#> 3      0-2
#> 4      1-2
#> 5      1-1
#> 6      1-3
#> 7      2-2
#> 8      2-1
#> 9      2-3
#> 10    2-00
#> 11    1-00
#> 12    3-00

## list
strings <- list( '0-0', '0-1' ,'0-2', '1-Feb', '1-Jan', '1-Mar', '2-Feb', '2-Jan', '2-Mar', 'Feb-00', '/Jan-00', 'Mar-00')
strings <- lapply(strings, month_num) 
tail(strings)
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "2-2"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "2-1"
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] "2-3"
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> [1] "2-00"
#> 
#> [[5]]
#> [1] "1-00"
#> 
#> [[6]]
#> [1] "3-00"
```

<sup>Created on 2019-02-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: When I do this, it outputs "list()".

Comment: @gracer if you edit your question with an example of your data, I can adjust the solution. From your question, I only have a character vector to work with. How is it stored? dataframe, list, vector?